# return an object that show which element was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns

**EDIT** the fact that I use closures and function is important. like the `gatherData()` and `voteSection()`

I want to click a div called `submitButton` this should tell me what the users have done. I have 3 sections. A voting section, a review section, and another type of voting section. the point is that right now I'm trying to set up the first voting section. When I click the `submitButton` I should get a an object that looks like `{vote:down}` or `{vote:up}` I only have two buttons in the voting section.

```
function gatherData(){
    var submitButton = ".submitButton";
    var result = {}
    function voteSection(){
        $(".upButton").click(function(){
            // result.vote = "up"
            //  console.log(result) ;
            $(this).data("clicked", true);
            $(this).siblings(".downButton").data("clicked",false)
        })
        $(".downButton").click(function(){
            $(this).data("clicked", true);
            $(this).siblings(".upButton").data("clicked",false)
            // result.vote = "down";
            //  console.log(result) ;
        })
    //    return result;
    }
    $(submitButton).on("click",function(){
        if($(".upButton").data("clicked")){
            result.vote = "up"
        }else if($(".downButton").data("clicked")){
            result.vote = "down";
        }
    })
    return result;
}
$(".submitButton").on("click",function(){
    console.log(gatherData())
})
```

Thanks for any help

EDIT
I realized I forgot to call `voteSection`

here's what I have now. it return an empty object

```
function gatherData(){
    var submitButton = ".submitButton";
    var result = {}
    function voteSection(){
        $(".upButton").click(function(){
            // result.vote = "up"
            //  console.log(result) ;
            $(this).data("clicked", true);
            $(this).siblings(".downButton").data("clicked",false)
        })
        $(".downButton").click(function(){
            $(this).data("clicked", true);
            $(this).siblings(".upButton").data("clicked",false)
            // result.vote = "down";
            //  console.log(result) ;
        })
        if($(".upButton").data("clicked")){
            result.vote = "up"
        }else if($(".downButton").data("clicked")){
            result.vote = "down";
        }
        // })
        return result;
    //    return result;
    }
   return voteSection()
    // $(submitButton).on("click",function(){

}
$(".submitButton").on("click",function(){
    console.log(gatherData())
})
```

Comment: click events know which element was clicked, and that's embedded directly in the event object which every event handler gets passed. beyond that, did you have a question? This site is for questions, not a place to dump your to-do list.

Comment: I am having problems tying everything together to return the object on the submit button.

Comment: You should have a variable that gets updated when the vote up or down button is pressed. Then you can get that when it is time to submit

Comment: Nothing stops you from wrapping closures around examples and help that people here are offering you. You can still do that.

Comment: Although you should be aware that a key problem with your code, is that every time you click submitButton, you are adding a new copy of event handlers.  So the 5th time a submit button is clicked, you will have 5 event handlers each on the upButton and downButton. Additionally, at the time you first click the submit button, you would have previously had no event listeners on upButton and downButton, so the first click of submit will always have an empty result object.

Answer (score 0):

**== UPDATE VERSION 2 == CLOSURE EXAMPLE**

Here is a second version that uses a closure that returns a function that can be called to acquire the current state.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xOjaJL

Notice the event handlers only bind to the dom 1 time per call voteGatherer(), the result of calling voteGatherer() is a function that you can call when you need the state of the vote.

```
function voteGatherer()
{
  var state = { 'vote': null }; // no vote selection made 

  $(".my-voting-button").click(function(ev)
  {
    var target = $(ev.target);
    state[target.data("action")] = target.data("value");
  });


  return function()
  { 
    return state;
  }
}

var gatherer1GetState = voteGatherer();

$(".my-submit-button").click(function(ev)
                             {
  $("#stateString").html(JSON.stringify(gatherer1GetState())) ;
});
```

**==== VERSION 1**

I threw together a code pen to help you manage state across these sections before you hit sumbit.  Check it out.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bZrxRk

```
<button data-value="up" data-action="vote" class="btn btn-primary my-voting-button">Vote Up</button>
<button data-value="down" data-action="vote" class="btn btn-warning my-voting-button">Vote Down</button>
```

Notice the voting buttons are attributed with an action and value that is updated on the state object.

So when you click the vote  up button, the `state["vote"]` value is set to `"up"`.  This can be applied to all of your fields.  You can just add the "my-voting-button" class to other button (and maybe rename the class to something that better fits your use case).

Here is the javascript that updates the state object:

```
var state = { 'vote': null }; // no vote selection made 

$(".my-voting-button").click(function(ev)
{
  var target = $(ev.target);
  state[target.data("action")] = target.data("value");
});
```

Now you have a state object that is fully populated, you can just sumbit that object with ajax back to your server. In my example I stringify it and write it out on the page.

```
$(".my-submit-button").click(function(ev)
{
  $("#stateString").html(JSON.stringify(state)) ;
});
```

Comment: thanks for the closure example.I'll have to see if this works with my implementation. I want to make sure that I could get all the data from all the different section and when the submit button is clicked send an ajax request with that data. In my code I use `voteSection` and then I have another section. I'll see if I can do that with your answer

Comment: you see it's not exactly what I want because in the votegather there will be a voting section and a review section and a range section. you didn't demonstrating tying those together that would be more helpful. I want to get into separating , decoupling code and stuff like that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should be able to extend my answer to make that happen.  If you post more of your code in your example, maybe I'll extend my example. From my point of view I've answered the question of "HOW" to do this.  You just need to apply what you learned from the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Below are three buttons and a div

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-cRpWjoSOw5KcyIOaZNo4i6fZ9tKPhYYb6i5T9RSVJG8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!--<script src="index.js"></script>-->
<title>repl.it</title>
</head>
<body>

    <button class="upButton">up</button>
    <button class="downButton">down</button>
    <button class="submitButton">submit</button>

    <div id="vote">vote goes here </div>

</body>
</html>
```

You could something like this to get the vote value given the previous html doc.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  var result = {vote:""}

  $(".upButton").click(function(){
     result.vote = "up";

  });

  $(".downButton").click(function(){
     result.vote = "down";

   });

   $(".submitButton").click(function(){
      $("#vote").html(result.vote); 

   });

  });
```

Comment: The point of this question wasn't about how to set and retrieve an object. It had to do more with passing along the object through different closures.  I wanted to organize the code into different sections for the different sections that the user inputs. your code shows everything in a document ready function which is "spaghetti code" and that is not what I want.

Comment: you should think about editing your question to say exactly what you mean